# Package Source Mapping error (even though its there)?

Tags: nuget, maui, nuget-package

I am getting a bunch of errors about Package Source Mapping. When I click Configure, it looks like a bunch of package source mappings are already there. Not sure what else I need to do?

**Error**:

```
Error   NU1100  Unable to resolve 'Xam.Plugin.Media (>= 6.0.2)' for 'net8.0-android34.0/android-arm'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org. AndroidPatientAppMaui   
    
Error   NU1100  Unable to resolve 'Plugin.Permissions (>= 6.0.1)' for 'net8.0-android34.0/android-arm64'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org. AndroidPatientAppMaui
```

Screenshots:
[image]

Comment: It just means its incompatible probably check that

Comment: I uninalled it and reinstalled it , and the errors seemed to have gone away.